# Почему USB Хаб работает только для USB 3?

Tags: usb, железо, usb3.0

[Купил хаб для USB 3.](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32906390022.html) Судя по всему, с устройствами USB 3 он работает хорошо (по крайней мере я пока проблем не заметил). А вот с USB 2 - никак.

Т. е. он годится для зарядки через кабели с разъёмом USB 2, но при попытке подключить USB 2 флешку или мышку ничего не происходит. Если подключить телефон, то он заряжается, но компьютер его не определяет. Если ту же самую USB 3 флешку подключить через измеритель питания, который по сути является переходником на USB 2, то она тоже не определяется.

Не понимаю, как такое вообще возможно...
Можно что-то с этим сделать?

---

Похоже, что связано с порядком подключения хаба к питанию и к компьютеру. При одновременном включении проблем не наблюдается, а не одновременно я включаю редко, поэтому точно сказать не могу. Но весьма вероятно, что usb2 не работает в тех случаях, когда к компьютеру подключается уже включенный в сеть хаб.

Comment: Марка и модель какая? Может, это дешёвое китайское поделие, нарушающее стандарты.

Comment: У меня есть юсб3-хаб, с которым юсб2-устройства таки работают, кроме одного - беспроводной мышки

Comment: По мотивам https://superuser.com/questions/1313667/usb-3-0-port-does-not-recognize-usb-2-0-devices предположу, что сбоит либо хаб (отдельный usb2-контроллер барахлит), либо хост (т. е. компьютер). Компьютер сейчас распознаёт проблемные мышь и флешку, поочерёдно подключенные напрямую в тот же usb3 порт, что и хаб? (проверка на то, не спалил ли хаб контроллер компьютера или эти два устройства)

Comment: Насчёт марки и модели: по ним можно погуглить отзывы, не является ли такая привередливость типовой проблемой серии.

Comment: Теоретически могу допустить что там нарушена распиновка +- данных, а вот с питанием всё нормально. Правда на практике я такого не встречал. Скорее всего брак, так как обратная совместимость должна быть обеспечена.

Comment: @Arhad, хаб китайский, но далеко не дешёвый.

Comment: @andreymal, нет не работает любое usb2-устройство. При этом на данный момент не попалось ни одного usb3, которое бы не работало.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev, добавил ссылку в вопрос.

Comment: Хм.. Возможно, сам заработал сейчас после включения компа...

Comment: Раз он сам заработал, то при очередном отказе надо будет разобрать и проверить пайку. Ну или закономерность в виде времени суток и освещённости установить (мало ли). Уже радует, что это не сбойный контроллер (такие штуки слишком просты, чтобы что-то помнить между запусками, так что либо они не работают вообще, либо работают стабильно).

Comment: @Arhad, а может что-то с драйверами было? Потому что ночью до выключения компа точно не работало, а утром после включения - уже нормально. Я тут ещё линукс пытался загрузить между этими действиями, но что-то он грузиться не захотел (впрочем, время на компе на 3 часа сбилось). А вообще, те же устройства через другой хаб определялись. Либо с защитой от перегрузок - хаб выключает порт (именно порт, не весь хаб) при попытке потребления больше 2 или 2.5 ампер, хотя вроде сейчас такая связь не подтвердилась. И ещё идея - монитор, но её я позже проверю.